# Not able to reuse the migrated from WSO2 IS 5.0.0 to WSO2 IS 5.2.0 tenants

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I recently updated my environment from WSO2 IS 5.0.0 to WSO2 IS 5.2.0. My environment consists of 2 machines that are creating a cluster (using the WKA membership scheme and Load Balancer(AWS ELB) with sticky session enabled). I am using MySQL(not the default H2 database). The machines on which the IS is deployed are Windows Server 2012 R2 (EC2 AWS machines).

I am also using the WSO2 IS multitenancy. When I was using IS 5.0.0 I had several tenants which I thought I had migrated properly by following the instructions mentioned in:
https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS510/Upgrading+from+a+Previous+Release
https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS520/Upgrading+from+a+Previous+Release

Unfortunately when I tried to use the password grant type with one of the profiles in one of the tenant I received the following response:
  {
    "error": "server_error",
    "error_description": "Internal Server Error."
  }
instead receiving valid access token. The error in the console log is

```
    [2016-10-21 15:41:34,941] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.OAuth2Service} -  Error occurred while issuing the access token for Client ID : klaFcti7TeDeEqFbzZr_HYKEEBga, User ID admin@admin.com@test
and Grant Type : password
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.wso2.carbon.identity.openidconnect.DefaultIDTokenBuilder.buildIDToken(DefaultIDTokenBuilder.java:147)
at org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.token.AccessTokenIssuer.issue(AccessTokenIssuer.java:268)
at org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.OAuth2Service.issueAccessToken(OAuth2Service.java:219)
at org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth.endpoint.token.OAuth2TokenEndpoint.getAccessToken(OAuth2TokenEndpoint.java:246)
at org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth.endpoint.token.OAuth2TokenEndpoint.issueAccessToken(OAuth2TokenEndpoint.java:110)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.performInvocation(AbstractInvoker.java:188)
at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:104)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:204)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:101)
at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:58)
at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:94)
at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:272)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:249)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:248)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:222)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:153)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:171)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:289)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doPost(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:209)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:265)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.doFilter(HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.java:120)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:218)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:99)
at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonTomcatValve$1.invoke(CarbonTomcatValve.java:47)
at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:57)
at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:47)
at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:62)
at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:159)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:57)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:442)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1082)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:623)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1756)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1715)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Then I tried creating brand new tenant and did the same case, but this time I was able to receive valid access token for the user.

Also when I try to login in the migrated from 5.0.0 tenants through the admin console, I receive the following error:
**[IS]ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.core.deployment.DeploymentInterceptor} -  Error while updating wso2carbon-sts in STSDeploymentInterceptor
java.io.IOException: Invalid keystore format**
Please, find attached the log file:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/jwstx6my3jcdjiz/Invalid%20keystore%20format.log?dl=0
It seems for some reason 5.2.0 is considering these keystores as invalid ones. I think these keystores are created upon tenant creation, so I am not quite sure what is causing this behavior and why WSO2 IS 5.2.0 considers the keystores of WSO2 IS 5.0.0 tenants as invalid.
The keystores exist.

Do you think this is related to some sort of misconfiguration or issue while migrating these tenants from 5.0.0 to 5.2.0? Is there a way to fix this behavior and not lose the tenants?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you see any error in wso2carbon.log file. If you can see, please attach the log file

Comment: Updated the post with links to the files that describe the different errors in the different scenarios. Here is a link to the entire console.log:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/vpndhfvgh3xn76x/TenantErrorsConsole.log?dl=0
I hope you find this information helpful.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

According to the error, it cannot find the registry key store. You can browse the tenant registry and check key store is existing or not.

keystore location :/_system/governance/repository/security/key-stores.

If the keys store is not existing, please check registry db configurations.

Thanks
Isura.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Does this means that the migration of the registry db eventually was not a successful (5.0.0 to 5.1.0)? In which tables should I double check whether the necessary information is filled in?

Comment: I checked the registry db configurations and indeed I had to modify one file. After I did that, the situation was a bit better. When I am logging in the admin console of a tenant I am able to see all the images and do not get errors about .css files in the log file. However I receive "Error while updating wso2carbon-sts in STSDeploymentInterceptor
java.io.IOException: Invalid keystore format" error: https://www.dropbox.com/s/jwstx6my3jcdjiz/Invalid%20keystore%20format.log?dl=0 . What should I update in order to resolve this issue?